# Regex add space at given positions

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext, credit-card

I am looking to format an AMEX and a ViSA card using the same handler (JAVA-Android)

For Visa I want to look like "1234 1234 1234 1234"

And I am using:

```
String initial = s.toString();
// remove all non-digits characters
String processed = initial.replaceAll("\\D", "");
// insert a space after all groups of 4 digits that are followed by another digit
processed = processed.replaceFirst("(\\d{4})(?=\\d)", "$1 ");
// to avoid stackoverflow errors, check that the processed is different from what's already
//  there before setting
if (!initial.equals(processed)) {
   // set the value
   s.replace(0, initial.length(), processed);
}
```

My question is:

Given that I have an array of the positions that need to pe replaced by " " (example [4,9,14]) how can I format this using a REGEX or any other methow to allow things like delete, paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `for` loop to insert character with 4 digits interval.

The balance the interval, keep `gap` variable and increase it during every iteration to keep the balanced position for space, considering the previous added spaces so use

```
String initial = s.toString();
// remove all non-digits characters
    String processed = initial.replaceAll("\\D", "");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(processed);
    System.out.println(sb);
    int gap = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i< sb.length()-1;i+=4){
        sb.insert(i + gap,' ');
        gap++;
    }
```

[**Demo Link**](https://ideone.com/Bw3T7g)

To handle both cases, you [can use this demo](https://ideone.com/Jt1pxw)

Comment: But if for example, I have 

gap = [4, 11]

input: 345678901234564

how can I output:

3456 789012 34564

Comment: then it's needs to be handled differently because there is no symmetry in the gap places , it should be done with hard coded value though now you are asking a different question

Comment: The core idea is that Visa card show has symmetric spaces while AMEX has not. My struggle was the AXEM in the format mentioned above (asymmetric). Can this be done with REGEX ?

Comment: it would be ugly and slow and even though you use regex, you will still required different cases (if) to handle different types because there is no indication in the input to add spaces according to different patterns